# the DataError: No numeric types to aggregate of creating pivot_table in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, shown as here. There are two time periods,`period-1(1998-01-01:1998-02-01)   period 2(1998-02-02-1998-05-02)`. I would like to transform this one into another dataframe, shown as in the second figure. Each entry of the second dataframe is the mean value of the ID in the corresponding time period).

[image]

[image]

As suggested by a friend here, here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["1002", "2001", "1002", "2003", "1002"],
                "Time": ["1998-01-02", "1998-02-03", "1998-04-05", "1998-02-03", "1998-01-20"],
                 "Price": ["34", "45", "23", "30","60"]})
print(df)

df.Time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
period2=pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('1998-02-02'), pd.Timestamp('1998-05-02'), closed='both')
df['Price'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['New']='period1'

df.loc[df.Time.apply(lambda x : x in period2),'New']='period2'
df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='New',values='Price',aggfunc='mean')
```

But I got the following error message, what might be the reason for that?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-1d40b807c09c> in <module>()
----> 1 df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='New',values='Price',aggfunc='mean')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot_table(self, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
   5298                            aggfunc=aggfunc, fill_value=fill_value,
   5299                            margins=margins, dropna=dropna,
-> 5300                            margins_name=margins_name)
   5301 
   5302     def stack(self, level=-1, dropna=True):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot_table(data, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
     81 
     82     grouped = data.groupby(keys, observed=dropna)
---> 83     agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
     84 
     85     table = agged

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   4656         axis=''))
   4657     def aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
-> 4658         return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   4659 
   4660     agg = aggregate

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   4087 
   4088         _level = kwargs.pop('_level', None)
-> 4089         result, how = self._aggregate(arg, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)
   4090         if how is None:
   4091             return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    346         if isinstance(arg, compat.string_types):
    347             return self._try_aggregate_string_function(arg, *args,
--> 348                                                        **kwargs), None
    349 
    350         if isinstance(arg, dict):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _try_aggregate_string_function(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    302         if f is not None:
    303             if callable(f):
--> 304                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
    305 
    306             # people may try to aggregate on a non-callable attribute

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1304         nv.validate_groupby_func('mean', args, kwargs, ['numeric_only'])
   1305         try:
-> 1306             return self._cython_agg_general('mean', **kwargs)
   1307         except GroupByError:
   1308             raise

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   3972                             min_count=-1):
   3973         new_items, new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(
-> 3974             how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count)
   3975         return self._wrap_agged_blocks(new_items, new_blocks)
   3976 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   4044 
   4045         if len(new_blocks) == 0:
-> 4046             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
   4047 
   4048         # reset the locs in the blocks to correspond to our

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem you forget assign back:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Better is:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'])
```

Also your code should be simplify with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask created by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df.Time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

df['Price']= df['Price'].astype(int)
df['New'] = np.where(df['Time'].between('1998-02-02','1998-05-02'), 'period2', 'period1')
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='New',values='Price',aggfunc='mean')
print (df1)
New   period1  period2
ID                    
1002     47.0     23.0
2001      NaN     45.0
2003      NaN     30.0
```